# How to pass a parameter to @onStart method in MyListener Class or to run a method before @onStart

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a parameterized method(`readConfig_1(String path)`) being called in @onStart method in MyListener class in a TestNG Suite

Here's the Parameterized Method, I have written which actually needs a path to where the XML file is stored.

```
public static void readConfig_1(String configXmlPath) 
{

            browser = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, "config",
                    "browser");
             env = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, "config", "env");
             release = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, "config", "release");
            serverName = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env,
                    "serverName");
             host = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "host");
            userName = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "userName");
            passWord = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "passWord");
            portNumber = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env,
                    "portNumber");
            schema = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "schema");
            url = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "url");
            screenShotForPass=CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "SCreenShotForPass");

            screenShotForFail=CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "SCreenShotForFail");


            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("****************************************************");
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("           Configuration Details                    ");
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("****************************************************");

            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("Browser ::" + browser);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("env ::" + env);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("serverName ::" + serverName);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("host ::" + host);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("userName ::" + userName);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("passWord ::" + passWord);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("portNumber ::" + portNumber);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("schema ::" + schema);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("url::" + url);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("ScreenSnapShotForPass::"+screenShotForPass );
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("ScreenSnapShotForFail::"+screenShotForFail );

        }
```

In this TestNG Suite seen below, I need to call the above method passing a parameter to it before it can go ahead and run the tests written in the other classes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.healthcare.reports.MyListener"></listener>
    </listeners>



    <test name="XYZ Tests">
        <classes>

            <class name="com.healthcare.utility.Config">
                <methods>
                    <include name="readConfig_1"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>

            <class name="com.healthcare.businessLib.xyz.AddUserTests" />

        </classes>

    </test>


</suite>
```

By this I intend to restrict a TestNG Suite to read a particular Config.XML file which will have it's own values such as Env, URL, browser etc., set before the tests can be executed. Is there a way I can achieve this?

--by the suggestions on other posts, I thought adding the readConfig_1 to a @BeforeClass annotation would resolve the problem. But there's more to it-----

My Listener Class has **@onStart** annotation which needs the config file to be run on the start of the Suite. As you see below my Listener Class has the variables **release_1** coming from Config file.

```
 public class MyListener implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

        // This belongs to ISuiteListener and will execute before the Suite start

        ReportLib report=new ReportLib();

        @Override
        public void onStart(ISuite arg0) {

            Config.readConfig_1(configXlsPath);
            ExportTestResults export = new ExportTestResults();
            export.exportExcelHeader(Config.release_1);
            CoreLib.fCreateLogger(Config.release_1);

        }
```

But if I put it in @BeforeClass in a TestClass these variables(`Config.release_1`) are returning null as they would be running before the test class. So I need the readconfig_1() to **run before or with the Listener class** and unable to add a parameter to the onStart(ISuite arg0). And neither can I run the readConfig Method in @BeforeClass

Tried a few things by :

1. Running the readConfig_1() in the TestNG.XML as the first method even before the listener class could be called.
2. putting a @BeforeClass annotation in the Listener class with `readConfig_1()` method parameterized in it- hoping that the readConfig would be called before the onStart() is executed.

   ```
   public class MyListener2 implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener{
   ```

   ReportLib report=new ReportLib();

   ```
       @BeforeClass
       @Parameters("configXlsPath")
       public void beforeSuite(String configXlsPath)
       {
           Config.readConfig_1(configXlsPath);
       }


       @Override
       public void onStart(ISuite arg0) {
           ExportTestResults export = new ExportTestResults();
           System.out.println("In onStart(Listener_2)"+ Config.release_1);
           export.exportExcelHeader(Config.release_1);
           CoreLib.fCreateLogger(Config.release_1);

       }
   }
   ```

But none worked. Is there a way around this now?

---Reposting this question from my previous---

Answer (score 0):

Put your `public static void readConfig_1(String configXmlPath)` in a class, make a test and call the test before `<listener>` and have the method read in listener class like this

```
<suite name="Default suite" thread-count="5" group-by-instances="false" verbose="1" allow-return-values="false" parallel="false" data-provider-thread-count="10" junit="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">
  <test verbose="2" name="pTest">

    <classes>
      <class name="firsttestngpackage.customParameter">
          <methods>
            <include name="getParams"/>
         </methods>
       </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <listeners>
      <listener class-name = "firsttestngpackage.myListener1" />
   </listeners>
  ...
  ...
```

below is `customeParameter class` , which is analogous to your `readConfig_1`

```
package firsttestngpackage;



public class customParameter {

    public static String getParams()  {

        return new String ("testParam1");
      }
}
```

and the `listener class`

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import firsttestngpackage.customParameter;

public class myListener1 implements ITestListener {

    String tParam = customParameter.getParams();
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {


        System.out.println("the method"  + "  "+result.getMethod().getMethodName() +"  "+ "passed and custom parameter is " + tParam);
    }
```

The above prints

`the method  gotoURL  passed and custom parameter is testParam1`

`gotoURL` is a method in my test class which I have not shown here . You should be able to do like above with `readConfig_1` method and call it in your listener class like `yourClass.readConfig_1`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this out today and let you know how that works for me.